# I want to construct a single list out of 2 python dictionaries which have same keys but different values for the keys

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have list of dictionaries:

```
a1 = [{'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x3': 3}]
a2 = [{'x1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'x3': 4}]
```

I need to combine the two lists into a 3rd list like:

```
a3 = [{'x1': 3, 'x2': 5, 'x3': 7}]
```

I googled and found that newer versions of Python have the concept of `collection.Counter`s, but I am working on `Python 2.6.4` which doesn't support `collections.Counters`.

Comment: show us your attempt

Answer (score 4):

You can use dictionary comprehension for Python dicts:

```
a1 = {'x1':1, 'x2':2, 'x3':3}
a2 = {'x1':2, 'x2':3, 'x3':4}

a3 = {
    key: a1.get(key, 0) + a2.get(key, 0)
    for key in set(a1.keys() + a2.keys())
}
```

Comment: That is not a generator. That is a dictionary comprehension

Comment: Oops, my fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `a1, a2` are dictionaries (that is `a1 = {x1:1,x2:2,x3:3}` instead of square brackets).

Assuming that they have common keys, you can do it by a *dictionary comprehension*

```
{key: a1[key]+a2[key] for key in a1}
```

Comment: This fails if any keys are in one dict but not the other.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I know, that's why I have written *assuming that they have common keys*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a1 = [{'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x3': 3}]
a2 = [{'x1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'x3': 4}]
final_list = [{a:a1[0][a]+b for a, b in a2[0].items()}]
```

Output:

```
[{'x2': 5, 'x3': 7, 'x1': 3}]
```

Comment: @Abhishek I do not know what you mean. The input values are exactly the same as those you posted. Do you mean that the output is incorrect?

Comment: I ran the code snippet you posted and landed in syntax error :

Comment: >>> a1 = [{'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x3': 3}]

>>> a2 = [{'x1': 2, 'x2': 3, 'x3': 4}]

>>> final_list = [{a:a1[0][a]+b for a, b in a2[0].items()}]
  File "<stdin>", line 1

    final_list = [{a:a1[0][a]+b for a, b in a2[0].items()}]
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Abhishek When I run this code, I receive no syntax error. Please check that you are actually using the code that is posted above and that there are no indentation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `collections.Counter` [recepie](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/) which was added to Python 2.7.
This is importable to Python 2.5+ so you can use it.

Then it simple as:

```
a1 = {1:1,2:2,3:3}
a2 = {1:2,2:3,3:4}
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter(a1)
c2 = Counter(a2)
c1.update(c2)
c1
Counter({3: 7, 2: 5, 1: 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code (and description) you have written do not make sense in Python. You are mixing up lists and dictionaries!

If you replace the square brackets `[` and `]` in your sample with braces `{` and `}` then you will make dictionaries.

Lists do not have keys. Dictionaries do.

Here is how you might combine two dictionaries in the way you want

```
# Alternative way of making two dicts
a = dict(a=1,b=2,d=3)
b = dict(a=4,b=5,c=6)

# make a set of all the keys
keys = set.union(set(a), set(b))

# Create a new dictionary combining the data in the first two
ab = { k : a.get(k,0) + b.get(k,0) for k in keys}

print(ab)
```

The output of this code is

```
{'c': 6, 'd': 3, 'a': 5, 'b': 7}
```

This code does not assume that the two dictionaries have identical sets of keys, so we first make a set of all the keys that can be found in your dictionaries.

Then we use a construct called a *dictionary comprehension*, which is just a shorthand syntax for constructing dictionaries from data you have stored elsewhere.

In the dict comprehension we loop over all the keys that we found earlier, and look up the corresponding values in our original dicts and add them together, before storing them in the new dict under the same key.

We have to use `d.get(key, 0)` rather than `d[key]` because the latter would raise a `KeyError` exception for the first key which was only present in one of the orginal dicts. The second argument to `get` is the value that should be returned in case the key is absent.